# Receive table values on click on different page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table containing 2 columns named S.No. and Book. In S.No. Value 1 2 3... And in Book column there is a submit button for each row. If I click on first submit button then it should print 1 and if I click on 2nd submit button then it should print 2 on different page (data.php)

Comment: Can we see your code? Click "edit" below your question and add your code.

Comment: Sorry, Actually I don't have any idea. How will I do this. I only want to know how value will change if I click on next row submit button.

Comment: We need to see your code, to check on your form, your rows and your submit button (we really need to see them, we can't just imagine your code).

Comment: Ok here's the table code..
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>S.No.</th>
<th>Book</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="submit">
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><input type="submit">
</tr>
</table>

and second page(data.php)

<form>
<label for="sno">S.No.</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you posted your table (in a comment!) I believe I understand what you want to achieve. I created two files, copy-pasted your code, and made some very little changes:

- In "books.php" the submit buttons are enclosed in "form" tags.
- "data.php" gets the book number from "$_POST".

Here are the files:

**books.php**

```
<table border="1"> 
  <tr> 
    <th>S.No.</th> 
    <th>Book</th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>1</td> 
    <td> <!-- THE BOOK NUMBER IS IN A HIDDEN FIELD OF THE FORM -->
      <form method="post" action="data.php">
        <input type="text" value="1" name="book" hidden> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
      </form>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>2</td> 
    <td> <!-- THE BOOK NUMBER IS IN A HIDDEN FIELD OF THE FORM -->
      <form method="post" action="data.php">
        <input type="text" value="2" name="book" hidden> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
      </form>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
// GET BOOK NUMBER FROM PREVIOUS PAGE.
if ( isSet( $_POST["book"] ) )
     $book = $_POST["book"];
else $book = "";

?>
<form> 
  <label for="sno">S.No.</label> 
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $book;?>">  <!-- DISPLAY BOOK NUMBER -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

What **SHiV with JARVIS** must do is to create two files with the given names, copy-paste previous code, open your browser and run `localhost/books.php`.

Comment: Thankyou Very much. You solved my problem. The magic was hidden attribute. You exactly did what I wanted to do.